# How to Assign Values from one JSON Object List from Another JSON Object List

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, filtering

I have two JSON objects: I need to substitute the values from the properties from the product JSON with values from the properties from the branch JSON.

This is about plain JavaScript.

I have tried it with map and filter but the problem is that when there is no brand for a certain product the application crashes and that should be prevented. I also tried it with map and if's see JSFiddle link below.

```
var product = {
  products: [{
      ID: 1,
      brandDescr: 'substitute', //this value should be substituded with the branch Description
      brandID: 1,
      colorCode: 2,
      colorDesc: 'substitute',
    },
    {
      ID: 2,
      brandDescr: 'substitute',
      brandID: 2,
      colorCode: 3,
      colorDesc: 'substitute',
    },
    {
      ID: 3,
      brandDescr: 'substitute',
      brandID: 12,
      colorCode: 3,
      colorDesc: 'substitute',
    }
  ]
}

var brand = {
  brands: [{
      Description: 'BMW',
      ID: 1
    },
    {
      Description: 'Mercedes',
      ID: 2
    },
    {
      Description: 'Audi',
      ID: 3
    },
  ]
}

/**mthis method crashes when there is no Description for a Brand.
 *for example for product ID 3 there is no brand description because brandID 
 * 12 does not exist
*/

product.products.forEach((x) => {
    x.brandDescr = brand.brands.filter(function (y) {
    console.log('Value: ' + x.brandID + y.ID)
    return x.brandID == y.ID
  })[0].Description
});
```

So the result should be that the brandDescr in product should be substituted with the Description from brand and when there is no matching Description in brand the application should not crash.

And because performance is an issue, it should be prevented to do a double filter: the first time to check if the array is not empty, so to check if there is a branchDescr available for a product and the second time to do the actual substitution.

I have created a JSFiddle at
https://jsfiddle.net/Ben197/wpcz21e7/88/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var product = {
  products: [{
      ID: 1,
      brandDescr: 'substitute', //this value should be substituded with the branch Description
      brandID: 1,
      colorCode: 2,
      colorDesc: 'substitute',
    },
    {
      ID: 2,
      brandDescr: 'substitute',
      brandID: 2,
      colorCode: 3,
      colorDesc: 'substitute',
    },
    {
      ID: 3,
      brandDescr: 'substitute',
      brandID: 12,
      colorCode: 3,
      colorDesc: 'substitute',
    }
  ]
}

var brand = {
  brands: [{
      Description: 'BMW',
      ID: 1
    },
    {
      Description: 'Mercedes',
      ID: 2
    },
    {
      Description: 'Audi',
      ID: 3
    },
  ]
}

product.products.forEach(productItem => {
    const maybeBrand = brand.brands.find(i => i.ID === productItem.brandID);
    if (maybeBrand) {
        productItem.brandDescr = maybeBrand.Description;
    }
});

console.log(product.products);
```

Comment: Thanks for your  help Maxim, this was where I was looking for !!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) you can use [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and instead of getting the first element (i.e.: ...[0].Description) you can use a different way to save the value:

```
product.products.forEach(function(ele, idx) {
   var descr = brand.brands.find((currele) => currele.ID == ele.brandID);
   // if descr is not undefined use descr.Description else use the default...
   ele.brandDescr = descr && descr.Description || ele.brandDescr;
});
```

```js
var product = {
    products: [{
        ID: 1,
        brandDescr: 'substitute', //this value should be substituded with the branch Description
        brandID: 1,
        colorCode: 2,
        colorDesc: 'substitute'
    },
        {
            ID: 2,
            brandDescr: 'substitute',
            brandID: 2,
            colorCode: 3,
            colorDesc: 'substitute'
        },
        {
            ID: 3,
            brandDescr: 'substitute',
            brandID: 12,
            colorCode: 3,
            colorDesc: 'substitute'
        }
    ]
}

var brand = {
    brands: [{
        Description: 'BMW',
        ID: 1
    },
        {
            Description: 'Mercedes',
            ID: 2
        },
        {
            Description: 'Audi',
            ID: 3
        },
    ]
}
product.products.forEach(function(ele, idx) {
    var descr = brand.brands.find((currele) => currele.ID == ele.brandID);
    ele.brandDescr = descr && descr.Description || ele.brandDescr;
});

console.log(product);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple snippet. This will work as you are wishing.

```
product.products.forEach((x) => {
  brand.brands.map(e=>{
    if(e.ID == x.brandID){
      product.products[x.ID-1].brandDescr = e.Description;
    }
  })
});

console.log(product.products);
```